# How to create a transaction that inserts but then returns the inserted data

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, sqlx

I am working on a REST API so I am trying to implement a way for users to create a new service ticket.

Everything is working fine except for when it comes to storing things in the db (postgres).

Here's a snippet of the transaction once it is generated:

```
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO service_request (id, ...)
VALUES (...);

INSERT INTO media (id, filename, ...)
VALUES (...),
(...),
(...);

INSERT INTO servicerequest_media(service_request_id, media_id)
values (..., ...),
(..., ...),
(...,...);

COMMIT;
```

Using sqlx prepared statements, I know that the result contains some metadata such as the last inserted id.  However, how can I add a `select` query to my transaction and get the results of that query?

```
stmt, err := s.db.Prepare(CREATE_SERVICE_REQUEST)
if err != nil {
    //// 
}
res, err := stmt.Exec()
if err != nil {
    ////
}
```

Or, do I need to do a 2nd query to get the result?

I am pretty new to this, so please let me know if I need to give more context.

Comment: Usually in an API you want to return an identifier for the newly created object so that callers can refer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Exec](https://golang.org/src/database/sql/sql.go?s=36377:36474#L1335) does not return the rows created or inserted. It only returns the last inserted element id.

If you would like to get the rows, you can consider using [Query](https://golang.org/src/database/sql/sql.go?s=38825:38894#L1422) or [QueryRow](https://golang.org/src/database/sql/sql.go?s=41774:41836#L1520).

```
rows, err := stmt.Query()
if rows.Next {
    // declare variable of any type string, int or struct
    rows.Scan(&variable) // string, int
    // or
    rows.Scan(&variable.field1, &variable.field2) // where field1, field2 are the properties of your struct
    // do whatever you want with the variable
}
```